# How to append a bytes array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to append bytes array variable.

```
x = 1
while(True):
    payload = b'sr,mac,x,y,Fire,'
    payload += bytes(x)
    x += 1
```

What I want to get is this result

```
First iteration: sr,mac,x,y,Fire,1
Second iteration: sr,mac,x,y,Fire,2
# and so on
```

But my `payload` variable doesn't get initialized every time loop body is executed. Any help or fixes?

Also the records get appended like `sr,mac,x,y,Fire,1sr,mac,x,y,Fire,2sr,mac,x,y,Fire,3` and so on.

Comment: I think, the expected result of the second iteration is false. Please check. Also add the current result of your code.

Comment: if you want `x` to be always 1, avoid incrementing it

Comment: i want it to be incremented, typing mistake

Comment: `http://www.dotnetperls.com/bytes-python` 
you can learn about byte python from this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating your `bytes` object correctly. `bytes(x)`, where `x`
is a positive integer, returns a sequence of `b'\x00'` bytes of length `x`.

Instead, you want to append `b'1'` and so forth. For this, you start
with an `int`, then convert to a `str`, then to `bytes`:

```
x = 1
s = str(x)
b = bytes(s, 'ascii')
```